# Haskell function with length-indexed vector and predicate constraint

Tags: haskell

Here is function f that takes only length indexed vector with length exacly 2.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Main where 
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving Show
type One = S Z
type Two = S One

data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Nil  :: Vec Z a
  (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a 

f :: (l ~ Two) => Vec l a -> a
f (e :> _) = e
```

What is the best way to write function which only takes list of length greater (or less) then 2 ?
So something like:

```
f :: (Gt l Two) => Vec l a -> a
f (e :> _) = e
```

Comment: Do you need it to be in form of a constraint? Why not `f :: Vec (S (S r)) a -> a`? Alternatively, do you need to use custom Peano numbers? `GHC.TypeLits` ships [with comparison operators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:-60--61-) that can be used in constraints.

Comment: I think constraint will be better: what if I want less then two or greater then 100 - to long type signature. Intresting to see how can this be achived with custom peano numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own `Gt` using type families.

```
type Gt :: Nat -> Nat -> Constraint
type family Gt n m where
  Gt Z _ = 'True ~ 'False
  Gt _ Z = ()
  Gt (S n) (S m) = Gt n m
```

Then, you can write `f` using a constraint.

```
f :: (Gt l Two) => Vec l a -> a
f (e :> _) = e
```

But I'm not sure if this is better than this.

```
f' :: Vec (S (S (S n))) a -> a
f' (e :> _) = e
```

Of course, it'd be cleaner to write `(Gt l Hundred) => ...` than `Vec (S (S (S ....))) a ...`, but you still need to write `Hundred` anyway.